# jar executable is dysfunctional while it is functional in Netbeans maven project

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox, executable-jar

I have a maven project in Netbeans.
Running it shows a GUI in which you can select and read files using a JFileChooser.
The file chooser has the method getSelectedFiles() which returns a File[] which then I feed into fileProccesing(File[] files) to read them using PDDocument.load(file) from Apache pdfBox depedency.
Debugging has led to the conclusion bellow.
When running in Netbeans it works fine but when it's running as a jar executable it stops at the PDDocument.load(file) command. However no IOException is thrown.
Ether JFileChooser getSelectedFiles() returns some abnormal type of files or my pom.xml is problematic in some way. You can see my pom.xml bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>application</groupId>
<artifactId>toolToManagePdfs</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>toolToManagePdfs</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId> 
        <version>2.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>
                                application.App
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal JAR does not contain or reference its dependencies at runtime. If you want to run a JAR, you need to either

- build an executable JAR with the maven assembly plugin or maven shade plugin.
- list the classpath explictly when running the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to have the jar files in the lib subdir:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>application.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin> 
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem stemmed from having all plugins inside `<pluginManagement></pluginManagement>`.
Moreover the configuration was incomplete and didn't include the dependencies inside the jar.Using maven-assembly-plugin fixed that.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    application.App
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```